# New Defect from Excecution Grid when Status is changed to failed

Tags: alm

I want to open the Defect Window from the TestSet's Execution Grid when the "TC_STATUS" is "failed"

The following code seems only to work when I perform a "full" run

```
Actions.Action("Defects.NewDefect").Execute
```

or

```
Actions.Action("StepsView.NewDefect").Execute
```

I already tried:

```
 Actions.Action("TestSetView.NewDefect").Execute
```

but this does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can post a new defect automatically each time test instance status is changed and link this new defect to currently selected test instance.

In Test Lab module script workflow put this code:

```
Sub TestSetTests_FieldChange(FieldName)
 On Error Resume Next

 If FieldName = "TC_STATUS" and TestSetTest_Fields.Field("TC_STATUS").Value = "Failed" Then
    Set BugFact = TDConnection.BugFactory
    Set NewBug = BugFact.AddItem(null)
    'Fill new defect fields
    NewBug.Summary = "New Defect"
    NewBug.Field("BG_SEVERITY") = "3-High"
    NewBug.Field("BG_STATUS") = "New"
    NewBug.Field("BG_DETECTION_DATE") = "2016-01-01"
    '...
    NewBug.Post()

    TestInstanceId = TestSetTest_Fields.Field("TC_TESTCYCL_ID").Value
    Set TestInstanceFact = TDConnection.TSTestFactory
    Set TestInstance = TestInstanceFact.Item(TestInstanceId)

    Set NewBugLinkFact = TestInstance.BugLinkFactory
    Set NewBugLink = NewBugLinkFact.AddItem(null)
    NewBugLink.TargetEntity = NewBug
    NewBugLink.Post
 End If

 On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Or if you are working with ALM 12.53, you can try executing masthead "New Defect" action available from all modules.

```
Actions.Action("HeaderActions.HeaderNewDefect").Execute
```